# How to hide columns from Intractive Grid Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to know How to hide columns from Intractive Grid Oracle Apex, for example

I have select list value as x,y,z

:P_SELECT_LIST

If :P_SELECT_LIST is x then show all the columns like name,email,number , if :P_SELECT_LIST is y then show only name column and same for z show only name column

Comment: "Hide" when ? At page rendering ? When a user changes the value of P_SELECT_LIST  ? Please describe the exact behaviour you're expecting in as much detail as possible: explain what the user does and how you expect the page to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column has a setting called "Server-side Condition".

For your example I would use

- Type: "Function Body"
- Language: "PL/SQL"
- PL/SQL Function Body:

```
    if :P_SELECT_LIST = 'X' or :P_SELECT_LIST = 'Y' THEN
       return true;
    else
       return false;
    end if;
```

Set this for each column according to your needs.

If you want this to change after selecting something in the :P_SELECT_LIST item you need to set "Page Action on Selection" to "Submit Page" in the Settings of the item :P_SELECT_LIST.